# The method '[]' was called on null exception flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using an API call to get some data. And I am calling that method in the init state so that it fetches the data as soon as the widget is added into the tree.

I am using that data in a Text widget, but it shows an error that **"The method '[]' was called on null"**.

Here is the code for your reference:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  final String username;
  Profile({this.username});
  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  var data;

  void getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http
        .get('http://codeforces.com/api/user.info?handles=${widget.username}');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    } else {
      print('Something went wrong.');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Handle - ${widget.username}'),
            Text(data['result'][0]['firstName']),            /*This line causes error*/
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The question is why the **data** field is null even though it is being called in the init state and the API call is also successful?

I have marked the line which gives the error using a comment.

Comment: result array does not contain any value as indicated by the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it could be happen because in the time that the request are being done, your `Profile` widget was already rendered, and you're not using `setState` in your `getData()` function, so, the widget will not render again.

In this case, you can do some changes in your code:

Use a setState in your getData method

```
void getData() async {
  http.Response response = await http
    .get('http://codeforces.com/api/user.info?handles=${widget.username}');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    setState(() {
      data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    });
  } else {
    print('Something went wrong.');
  }
}
```

Set a default value to your Text widget

```
Text(data != null ? data['result'][0]['firstName'] : ''),
```

Answer (score 0):

not the best and efficient solution but if you just want to show some data like username or email you can do it like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(Profile());

class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  final String username;
  Profile({this.username});
  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  var email;
  void getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'http://codeforces.com/api/user.info?handles=${widget.username}'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
        email = map['result'][0]['email'];
        print(email);
      });
    } else {
      print('Something went wrong.');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: email == null
              ? CircularProgressIndicator()
              : Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text('Handle - ${widget.username}'),
                    Text(email),
                  ],
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

output:

[image]